# Graphing the derivative at a point

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. The function gives the surface $\{x,y,f(x,y)\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Fix a point $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. The derivative of $f$ at $(a,b)$ is the function $Df(a,b):\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$.

My question is, what does the graph of $Df(a,b)$ look like. How is the surface $\{(x,y,(Df(a,b)(x,y)))\}$ related to the graph of $f$?

Answer (score 1):

The graph $\{\big (x,y,f(a,b)+Df(a.b)(x,y)\big )\}$ is a plane, and it is tangent to the surface. That is, if you translate the graph $\{\big (x,y,Df(a,b)(x,y)\big )\}$ along the $Z$ axis, you can obtain a plane tangent to the surface at the point $(a,b,f(a,b))$. The distance of that translation is $f(a,b)$ (if it is negative, the translation is "downwards", if you know what I mean).

Comment: I thought that the gradient of $f(x,y)-z$ gives the normal to the tangent plane. That is the tangent plane at the point $(a,b,f(a,b))$ is $\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{(a,b)}(x-a)+\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|_{(a,b)}(y-b)-(z-(f(a,b))$. I'm not sure I understand, how do you translate the graph $\{(x,y,Df(a,b)(x,y)\}$ to obtain this tangent plane

Comment: @JonHerman Adding $f(a,b)$. If you add a constant $t$ to a function, its graph gets translated $t$ units "upwards" if $t>0$ or $-t$ units "downwards" if $t<0$.

Comment: But the set $\{(x,y,(Df(a,b))(x,y))\}=\left\{(x,y,z) \ ;\ \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{(a,b)}x+\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|_{(a,b)}y-z=0\right\}$. So the set $\{x,y,f(a,b)+(Df(a,b))(x,y)\}=\left\{(x,y,z) \ ;\  \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{(a,b)}x+\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|_{(a,b)}y+f(a,b)-z=0\right\}$. How is this set equal to the tangent plane at $(a,b,f(a,b))$ which is $\left\{(x,y,z) \ ; \  \left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{(a,b)}(x-a)+\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right|_{(a,b)}(y-b)-(z-f(a,b))=0\right\}$?